# Function wont fire after custom post type is updated

Tags: functions

I have a problem. I cant get this function to fire after a CPT called 'review' is updated on the front of the website. That's fine and the CPT updates with no issues but I need to function to fire after it has been updated.

```
function on_CPT_review_publish( $post_id, $post ) {
// ----------------- Start of Function -----------------

   $post_type = get_post_type($post_id);

    // If this isn't a 'review' post, don't update it.
    if ( "review" != $post_type ) return;

// -------------------- Grab details to work with -----------------------

// Get Review details
$reviewID = $post_id;

//Check if its ok to continue if the review has been completed, if not, just stop
$reviewComplete = get_post_meta($reviewID,'review_completed',true);
if ($reviewComplete != 1) return;

// Get Review details
$post_review_details = get_post( $reviewID ); 
$review_title = $post_review_details->post_title; 
$date_of_review_request = get_post_meta($reviewID,'date_of_review_request',true);

$the_book_review = get_post_meta($reviewID,'the_book_review',true);
$review_rating = get_post_meta($reviewID,'review_rating',true);
$chapters_in_hooked = get_post_meta($reviewID,'chapters_in_hooked',true);

//Book Details  
$bookID = get_post_meta($reviewID,'review_book_id',true);
$bookAuthorID = get_post_meta($reviewID,'book_author_id',true);
$bookRating = get_post_meta($reviewID,'review_rating',true);

//Author Details
  $Author_info = get_userdata($bookAuthorID);
  $AuthorName = $Author_info->user_login;
  $AuthorEmail = $Author_info->user_email;



// ---------- Update stuff! -----------

  // Update Reviewers Date and time taken to read books
  $todaysDate = date('d/m/Y');
  update_post_meta( $reviewID, 'date_review_completed', $todaysDate );

  // Calculate days taken to read books
  $diff = date_diff($date_of_review_request,$todaysDate);
  $daysTakenToReview = $diff->format("%a");
  update_post_meta( $reviewID, 'total_days_taken_to_review', $daysTakenToReview );


// ---------- Send emails -----------------


$mailfrom = 'webmasterarc3@veedence.co.uk';

$to = $AuthorEmail;
$subject = 'ARCReaders.com - Book Review - ' . $review_title;

$body = 'Hey ' . $AuthorName . ')!<br /><br /><br />';
$body .= 'We got a new ' . $review_rating . '* review for your book!<br />';

$headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8'); 

wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers );


// ----------------- End of Function -----------------  

     }
add_action( 'save_post', 'on_CPT_review_publish', 10, 2 );
```

I cant see whats wrong! I've tried setting it from 10 to 100 but no difference.

Comment: Have you tried with a simple dummy function (e.g. send a simple email) to debug if it's a problem with the hook or of the function itself?

Comment: Before anything else I'd make sure that the function is actually being hooked and run. Add `echo "on_CPT_review_publish ran"; die();` as the 1st line of the function. If hooked correctly then you'll get a blank page with the text at the top.

Comment: @Peter OK, will try that and let you know.